# How to create entries in db with incremental id in reactive programming?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

I am new to reactive programming. Need help to understand the behavior.

What i want to achieve ?

I want to create 50 entries whose id should be in incremental order. If an entry with id 1 is present in db then it should create entry with id 2.

My current implementation is as below:

```
// create entry 50 times 
 void createEntries() {
        LOGGER.info("going to create 50 entries);
        Flux.range(1, 50)
            .flatMap(i -> createEntry(5))
            .subscribe();
    }

//method to create an entry in db with incremental id  
private Mono<Integer> createEntry(long retryInterval) {
    return (customRepository.findAllEntry()) //-->A db call which returns all entries flux<Entrys> 
            .map(entry -> entry.getEntryId())
            .sort()
            //get last existing entry id
            .last(0)          
            //try to create the entry with new incremented id
            .flatMap(id -> createEntry(id + 1, retryInterval));
}

private Mono<? extends Integer> createEntry(int newEntryId, long retryInterval) {
    return saveEntry(newEntryId) //--> return Mono<Boolean> true if saved false if id already exists
            .doOnNext(applied -> LOGGER.info("Successfully created entry with id: {} ? {} ", newEntryId, applied)) //--> Why this is called multiple times??
            .flatMap(applied -> !applied
                    //applied false shows id already exists, so try again recursively with new incremented id
                    ? createEntry(newEntryId + 1, retryInterval)
                    : Mono.just(newEntryId))
            .doOnError(e -> LOGGER.warn("Error creating entry with id {} ? {} : ", newEntryId, e));
            .retryWhen(Retry.anyOf(RuntimeException.class)
                            .exponentialBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(retryInterval), Duration.ofSeconds(retryInterval))); //-->retry on creation if any exception 
}
```

The above implementation gives me unexpected behavior the info logger **"Successfully created entry with id:"** is getting invoked multiple times for same id ..however i am expecting to get it called only once.
Note: the behavior remains same even if i remove `retryWhen`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figure out the issue in my code. The problem was in below code snippet

```
// create entry 50 times 
 void createEntries() {
        LOGGER.info("going to create 50 entries);
        Flux.range(1, 50)
            .flatMap(i -> createEntry(5))
            .subscribe();
    }
```

This was invoking the method 50 time before even the `saveEntry(newEntryId)` was completed. I fixed the issue by using `repeat` api as below:

```
// create entry 50 times 
 void createEntries() {
        LOGGER.info("going to create 50 entries);
        createEntry(5).subscribe();
    }

//method to create an entry in db with incremental id  
private Flux<? extends Integer> createEntry(long retryInterval) {
    return (customRepository.findAllEntry()) //-->A db call which returns all entries flux<Entrys> 
            .map(entry -> entry.getEntryId())
            .sort()
            //get last existing entry id
            .last(0)          
            //try to create the entry with new incremented id
            .flatMap(id -> createEntry(id + 1, retryInterval))
            .repeat(49); //-->This fixes my issue will only be invoked  49 times again onComplete(). And hence will create 50 entries
}

private Mono<? extends Integer> createEntry(int newEntryId, long retryInterval) {
    return saveEntry(newEntryId) //--> return Mono<Boolean> true if saved false if id already exists
            .doOnNext(applied -> LOGGER.info("Successfully created entry with id: {} ? {} ", newEntryId, applied)) 
            .flatMap(applied -> !applied
                    //applied false shows id already exists, so try again recursively with new incremented id
                    ? createEntry(newEntryId + 1, retryInterval)
                    : Mono.just(newEntryId))
            .doOnError(e -> LOGGER.warn("Error creating entry with id {} ? {} : ", newEntryId, e));
            .retryWhen(Retry.anyOf(RuntimeException.class)
                            .exponentialBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(retryInterval), Duration.ofSeconds(retryInterval))); //-->retry on creation if any exception 
}
```